# server vs client defined in remote desktop control

Tags: networking

when controlling a computer remotely from another one , mouse etc , what criteria is used to define which of the 2 computers is the server .i read up on how to accomplish the remote control  and was successful but found "server" vs "client" wording in the instructions very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Simply put:

- Server: target system you're trying to reach via (say) ssh, or the machine offering a remote service,
- Client: the machine that is making the entry into the remote server or another machine to get a service.

Perhaps using this analogy: a bank and a customer. Here a bank is a server, rendering a service, and the customer is, of course, is the client seeking a service from the bank (server).